# TypeError at / Insertdetails() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' - Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting the following error in a Django project

> TypeError at / Insertdetails() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
> Request Method:   POST
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> Django Version:   4.2.7
> Exception Type:   TypeError
> Exception Value:
> Insertdetails() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
> Exception Location:   D:\Works\django\projects\proj1\proj1\views.py, line 9, in Insertdetails
> Raised during:    proj1.views.Insertdetails
> Python Executable:    C:\Users\ankilla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.11.6

I am totally new to Django, I need to insert data into mysql from HTML page. I was following a old video

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9fx8qrJyCY

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from proj1.models import Insertrecord
from django.contrib import messages

def Insertdetails(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
               
            saverecord=Insertdetails()
            saverecord.ID=request.POST.get('ID')
            saverecord.Name=request.POST.get('Name')
            saverecord.Email=request.POST.get('Email')
            saverecord.Address=request.POST.get('Address')
            saverecord.save()
            
            messages.success(request,'Saved')
            return render(request,'index.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'index.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Insertrecord(models.Model):
    ID=models.IntegerField()
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table="employee"
```

Index.html

```
        <form method="post">
        Emp Id        : <input type="number" name="ID">
        Employee Name : <input type="text" name="Name">
        Email         : <input type="text" name="Email">
        Address       : <input type="text" name="Address">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit
        </form>
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.Insertdetails)
]
```

Please help

Followed the same as video to insert data into mysql

Comment: This line(`saverecord=Insertdetails()`) should be `saverecord= Insertrecord()`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, Thanks brother it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make an instance of the `Insertrecord` class but mistakenly called the `Insertdetails` function. To fix it, change `saverecord=Insertdetails()` to `saverecord=Insertrecord()`.